# C# .NET 4.0/4.5 UDP send issue

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, udp

I am working on writing a network library in C# and originally had used the .NET 3.5 Framework.  I recently decided to switch to .NET 4.5 but started running into an issue with sending UDP packets.  What I'm running into is if UDP packets are sent too fast, the `Socket.SendToAsync` method completes with a `SocketError` of `AddressFamilyNotSupported` and the packets are never sent.

If I switch the project to .NET 3.5, I never run into the issue no matter how hard I try to repeat it.  This also can be reproduced in .NET 4.0.

Here is a [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11540065/UdpTest.zip) to the project I put together to reproduce the issue.  If you spam the "ClientSnd" or "ServerSnd" buttons you'll see the error occur.  Switch the project to .NET 3.5 and spam all you want... no issues at all.

I haven't been able to find much useful information searching on this issue.  Any ideas?

**EDIT (added code from the sample project demoing the issue):**

Here's where the binds are happening for both the client and server:

```
            byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[32768];
            byte[] serverBuffer = new byte[32768];

            IPEndPoint clientLocalEndPoint = GetLocalIPEndPoint(0, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            IPEndPoint serverLocalEndPoint = GetLocalIPEndPoint(6337, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

            m_ClientSocket.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;
            m_ServerSocket.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;
            m_ClientSocket.Bind(clientLocalEndPoint);
            m_ServerSocket.Bind(serverLocalEndPoint);

            m_ClientSendArgs.RemoteEndPoint = GetRemoteIPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 6337, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            m_ClientRecvArgs.RemoteEndPoint = m_ClientSocket.LocalEndPoint;

            m_ServerSendArgs.RemoteEndPoint = GetRemoteIPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", ((IPEndPoint)m_ClientSocket.LocalEndPoint).Port, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            m_ServerRecvArgs.RemoteEndPoint = m_ServerSocket.LocalEndPoint;

            m_ClientSendArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnClientCompletion);
            m_ClientRecvArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnClientCompletion);
            m_ServerSendArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnServerCompletion);
            m_ServerRecvArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnServerCompletion);

            m_ClientRecvArgs.SetBuffer(clientBuffer, 0, clientBuffer.Length);
            m_ServerRecvArgs.SetBuffer(serverBuffer, 0, serverBuffer.Length);

            ClientReceive();
            ServerReceive();
```

The `GetRemoteIPEndPoint` and `GetLocalIPEndPoint` methods:

```
    private static IPEndPoint GetRemoteIPEndPoint(string address, int port, AddressFamily addressFamily)
    {
        IPAddress[] ipAddresses = null;

        ipAddresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(address);

        List<IPEndPoint> ipEndPointList = new List<IPEndPoint>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ipAddresses.Length; i++)
        {
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipAddresses[i];

            if (ipAddress.AddressFamily == addressFamily)
            {
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

                ipEndPointList.Add(ipEndPoint);
            }
        }

        return ipEndPointList.ToArray()[0];
    }

    private static IPEndPoint GetLocalIPEndPoint(int port, AddressFamily addressFamily)
    {
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = null;

        switch (addressFamily)
        {
            case AddressFamily.InterNetwork:
                {
                    localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);

                    break;
                }
            case AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6:
                {
                    localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, port);

                    break;
                }
        }

        return localEndPoint;
    }
```

**Since this happens regardless of who sends the data (client or server), I'll focus on the client being the sender:**

Clicking the `ClientSnd` button:

```
    private void Button_ClientSnd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello there.  Just testing.  Nothing to see here.  Move along.");

            m_ClientSendQueue.Enqueue(buffer);

            if (!m_ClientTransmitting)
            {
                m_ClientTransmitting = true;

                ClientSendBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
```

Sending methods for the client:

```
    private void ClientSendBuffer()
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            if (m_ClientSendQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                byte[] buffer = m_ClientSendQueue.Dequeue();

                m_ClientSendArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                ClientSend();
            }
            else
            {
                m_ClientTransmitting = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ClientSend()
    {
        if (!m_ClientSocket.SendToAsync(m_ClientSendArgs))
        {
            OnClientCompletion(this, m_ClientSendArgs);
        }
    }
```

Completion callback for the client:

```
    private void OnClientCompletion(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        SocketError socketError = e.SocketError;

        if (socketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            ClientConsoleWrite("SocketError: {0}\r\n", socketError);
        }

        switch (e.LastOperation)
        {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.SendTo:
                {
                    if (socketError == SocketError.Success)
                    {
                        ClientConsoleWrite("Client message sent!\r\n");
                    }

                    ClientSendBuffer();

                    break;
                }
            case SocketAsyncOperation.ReceiveFrom:
                {
                    int bytesTransferred = e.BytesTransferred;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesTransferred];

                    Buffer.BlockCopy(e.Buffer, e.Offset, buffer, 0, bytesTransferred);

                    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

                    ClientConsoleWrite("Message received: {0}\r\n", message);

                    ClientReceive();

                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant snippets to your question. Many people don't have time to download, extract, and run a example project. Mainly can you post where you set the address in your example code?

Comment: I understand.  I posted the relevant snippets to my question.

Comment: in GetRemoteIPEndPoint you have `catch { }`, why are you throwing away all your exceptions? You likely have a exception happening, missing it, and are returning null for address. Remove that try-catch and see what error you get.

Comment: I copied that snippet from a support library that I created that actually handled exceptions, but instead of just removing the try/catch, I left the empty catch there instead.  I removed it but it didn't make a difference since GetRemoteIPEndPoint is called once when the sockets are binding.  This issue happens after sending data "too fast" and only is reproducible on .NET 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: I noticed that when it's being called from the UI is where it seems to happen.  If I click the "ClientSnd" button then hold enter down to spam it, this issue occurs.  If I create a while loop which sends the buffer 10,000 times, and click the "ClientSnd" button once (where the new while loop is located), it works fine.  If I click the button again and send the buffer another 10,000 times, it fails.

Comment: If you are writing a library to familiarise yourself with sockets, hats off to you. If on the other hand it's an ends to a mean, so that you don't necessarily have to reinvent the wheel, checkout http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/ and http://www.networkcomms.net. Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers for networkcomms.net.

Comment: @MarcF: I appreciate the links and have checked out lidgren before.  I've written quite an extensive library already.  I originally started the project back in 2008 to familiarize myself with sockets and then decided to continue development to use it for my own purposes.  It supports TCP and UDP and I've built a unique protocol around it but this was all done in .NET 3.5.  I recently revisited the project and decided to switch to .NET 4.5 and this issue punched me in the face, hard.  It doesn't seem to make any sense.  I'll check out networkcomms.net.  I'm always interested in other libraries.

Comment: I tested using UdpClient instead of using Socket directly and I can't reproduce it with the UdpClient.  using ILSpy, I found that UdpClient uses the Socket.BeginSend method.  So if I switch to Socket.BeginSend vs. Socket.SendToAsync (new .NET 3.5 async socket methods), then it'll work fine.  I prefer to use the new async socket methods, so I'll keep on trying to figure this out.

Comment: I found out what's causing this error.  If I create a new SocketAsyncEventArgs before each send, I can't reproduce the error.  If I reuse the same SocketAsyncEventArgs, I eventually run into this error.  I verified that the args are used in a thread safe context and the only modification to it is the SetBuffer for each send call.  These args are supposed to be reusable, and in fact for receiving I have no problems reusing them there.  I also don't have any problems reusing them in .NET 3.5 for sending.  Very strange that in 4.0 and 4.5 I can't reuse the args for sending.  Sounds like a bug...

Comment: I should also note that this is NOT a problem for TCP on .NET 4.0 and 4.5.  In fact, the TCP implementation I built is identical to the UDP implementation (as far as the structure of reusing the args and queueing data to be sent using locking for thread safety).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.  This issue is happening because the underlying buffer on the variable m_ClientSendArgs is constantly being changed using `SetBuffer`:

```
byte[] buffer = m_ClientSendQueue.Dequeue();

m_ClientSendArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

When I assigned a static buffer to it and used Buffer.BlockCopy, the issue went away:

```
byte[] buffer = m_ClientSendQueue.Dequeue();

Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, m_ClientSendBuffer, 0, buffer.Length);

m_ClientSendArgs.SetBuffer(0, buffer.Length);
```

So I've been implementing it wrong all along.  It's strange that it wasn't an issue on .NET 3.5, or an issue for TCP on .NET 4.0/4.5.